# Trying to move from one fragment to another with a button

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So my goal is to swap from my CalculatorFragment to my CalculatorResultsFragment using a parent FrameLayout through a a button. I'm getting the error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08020f (com.example.flexplan:id/parent_fragment) for fragment CalculatorResultsFragment{1046933} (71b49e01-2328-4454-870b-5acb04ccc3d0 id=0x7f08020f)
```

**fragment_calculator_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Calculator.CalculatorParentFragment">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent_fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CalculatorParentFragment.java**

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.parent_fragment, new CalculatorFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

**CalculatorFragment.java**

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.parent_fragment, new CalculatorResultsFragment());
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Error says you do not have view for your fragment, check your layout files, for each fragment you need to have one layout, if not transaction can not send you there. After all layouts in place, follow the docs [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#java) like so:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);

transaction.replace(R.id.parent_fragment, CalculatorResultsFragment.class, null);

transaction.commit();
```